# Filtering my annotation

Tags: python, django, annotations, django-views

I have this chunk of code which adds up all the players hurt on one team.

```
teams = Team.objects.annotate(team_count=Count('Team played for')).order_by('city')
```

I am having an issue however.  It is currently adding all injuries, but I would like to count just the players that are currently injured, or more specifically... where `returned=False`

Here are my models for a bit more context.

Team models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name='City', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    team_name =  models.CharField(verbose_name='Team Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    team_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    team_affiliation = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.city, self.team_name)
```

**EDIT added player models.py**

```
class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='Team played for')
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, related_name="Position")
    pob = models.CharField(verbose_name='Place of Birth', max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    dob = models.DateField()
    age =  models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    height = models.CharField(verbose_name='Height', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    weight = models.CharField(verbose_name='Weight', max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    drafted_by = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name='drafted by', null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Injury models.py

```
class PlayerInjury(models.Model):
    player =  models.ForeignKey(Player)
    injury_type = models.ForeignKey(Injury)
    injury_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Injured On', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name='Description', max_length=180, null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status)
    projected_return = models.DateField(verbose_name='Projected Return Date', null=True, blank=True)
    hide = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    returned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    source = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    source_label = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s - %s' % (self.player, self.injury_type)
```

Is there a way I can filter the annotation so that it will only count the currently injured players?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter before calling annotate: `.filter(player__playerinjury__returned=False).annotate(...)`.

Comment: That doesnt work due to the fact I am using annotate on the team object, which doesn't have returned as a variable

Comment: I am still seeing this error `FieldError at /team/` it doesn't like `player`

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice you specified a `related_name` on that one, which is not a good `related_name` anyways. `related_name` is what the attribute on your model that returns the related manager should be called, and thus, shouldn't have spaces. It should also be named after the reverse relationship. "Team.team_played_for" makes no sense. What it should be is something like "Team.players". At the very least, take out the spaces, and then use whatever you change it to in place of `player` in the query.

Comment: thanks for related_name info Chris.  One final question.  I made the changes but now I am not getting any info to display.  Now is that because most of them dont have any injured players currently?  Do I adjust that on the template?  ex. so if they have 0 injured players, still show team name and 0